# How to redirect to a PHP page?

Tags: php, redirect

On my PHP website there is a purchase page. I am thinking of adding a `thankyou.php` after successfully purchasing from `https://secure.shareit.com/shareit/checkout.html?productid=`

How can I create a Thank You page and redirect customers to that page after successfully purchasing my product?

Comment: please refer to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have figured it out if the user has done payment successfully.

If it success redirect to success.php

```
header("Location: success.php");
```

If it fails redirect to error.php

```
header("Location: error.php");
```

Also, if you want to send him on the location where he started payment do this and use status to show him success/failure

```
header("Location: main.php?status=error") OR header("Location: main.php?status=success")
```

you can access this variable by doing this $_GET['status'].

Comment: Hello Nilesh, 

I am new in PHP and I am only looking for redirecting customers to my thankyou.php page after successfully purchasing.

Can you please provide me complete coding and steps for the same??

Comment: @user12883408 Can you explain it with some more detail?

Comment: Hey.. If you have any condition to check to the purchase done, use the header: code to redirect to the new location

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Let's say completing purchase is inserting the records to a table without any errors. Once its inserted successfully you can redirect to different page using `header` function.

```
global $DBConnect;
$Query = "INSERT INTO posts(datetime,title,category,author,image,post)
          VALUES('$DateTime','$Title','$Category','$Admin','$Image','$Post')";
$Execute = mysqli_query($DBConnect,$Query);

if($Execute){
   //Success
   header("Location: thanks-page.php");
}else{
   //Error
   header("Location: error-page.php");
 }
```